# How to click button from a label using webdriver selenium

Tags: python, forms, selenium, automation, webdriver

I literally new with web **scraping** and selenium.

I was trying to click the label button, so, if the label clicked, the color will be change, like the picture below.

[image]

I think, it can be done by accessing the input 'id', but it won't work, I was trying to click the id button using this syntax

```
button = driver.find_element_by_id('r0_1')
button.click()
```

But the error I got is something like this

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable`

So, I think I should click the label to get access into the 'for' element. **Is anyone know how to click the label with the 'for' element because that one is an unique value also?**

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

*Note: This code is rebuilt from the original [link](http://www.humanmetrics.com/cgi-win/jtypes2.asp) in case to make it easier to read

Here is the link for the source code: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FfjvWXmq2-P7Q60ctm2SuCTDAQA3d6YF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: no sir, you don't have to ask me, you deserve it. Thank you!!! 
if may, please also vote up this question, perhaps another can be helped to from you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this way

**By label**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver,2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='r0_3']")))  

element.click()
```

**The below will click based on the input**

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='r0_3']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
```